# Software in AppCenter aren't up to date

Tags: release-loki, applications, software-installation, appcenter

I'm relatively new with ElementaryOS (and with Linux in general). An University advisor suggest us to try different distro for a more reproducible approach with our researches.

I'm trying ElementaryOS but every software that I search and install form the default AppCenter appear to be not at the latest version. (qGis, rstudio, texstudio, biblio manager, etc are all with a version number that not coincide with the latest version on the official sites).
I read many threads and blogs online that suggest to use a different package manager (like gnome software).
Can someone "route" me in the right direction? Is there a chance to use directly the packages on the sites of each software? What is the most efficient way to install up to date software on the go?

P.S. If I search Gnome software in the AppCenter, it is at old version too. There is a way to install this old version and after that force in some way the update, maybe from itself?

Kind regards, and sorry for the bad english, I'm writing on the go and this environment is a bit estranging at first.

Comment: What piece of software or what feature do you need exactly that is missing from the version shipped with elementary OS?

Comment: In my department we are required to have at least a long term release of all the software, but is highly recommended to have the latest version.
For QGIS, Latex, and R I think that I need to install from their repository and not from the default, I am wrong? Because they aren't present in the App Center. R Studio too.
In the App Center there are Texstudio and Kbibtex, but their versions are not the latest reported in their official site.
For what I see surfing the web this is a common thing with linux, there is a method to install directly from the websites the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1)
You could add some "custom" Repositories which contain the latest versions of you desired programs. The Ubuntu/ElementaryOS repos sometimes are out of date

Approach 2)
You could Download the Software directly from some Website

Answer (score 1):

To supplement felix's answer, you can use Snaps, if they're available. They are often more updated than the repositories and have a beta / unstable channel.